# How do I restore high-quality bluetooth audio after Teams call?

Tags: 20.04, sound, bluetooth, microsoft-teams

My bluetooth headset has two fidelity modes: high-fi audio for normal use
and low-fi audio which is normally used only during calls.

During a Teams call the mode changes to low-fi. But after the call hangs up the
headset is stuck in low-fi mode.

It affects all sound emitted by the computer.

As soon as I exit Teams, the audio mode returns to high-fi.

So I have gotten into the habit of restarting Teams immediately after every call. This interrupts my workflow and is made worse by repeating a MFA login process.

I expect that this is a bug in Teams, and I have reported it on Microsoft's [UserVoice site](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/908686-bug-reports/suggestions/43322505-post-call-restart-fixes-bluetooth-audio-fidelity).

Here I'm asking for a less-disruptive workaround. Can I restore the audio quality without restarting Teams?

My system information:

- Teams version teams/stable,now 1.4.00.7556 amd64
- Bose QuietComfort 35 II
- Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
- Lenovo ThinkPad T480s

Comment: Have you tried toggling the profile in system settings?

Comment: @ChanganAuto what does "toggling the profile" mean? Do you mean to disconnect and reconnect the bluetooth headset?

Comment: No, I meant changing from HFP (mono+mic) to A2DP (stereo).

Comment: @ChanganAuto I turned your hints into an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restore the high-fidelity audio by changing the configuration of the output device in the sound settings menu.

1. Open the dialog for the connected device.

   [image: Image shows the bluetooth settings connected device dialog.]
2. Click the "Sound Settings" button.
3. Find the output section of the Sound Settings. Observe that the configuration in the output is "**Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP)**".

   [image: Image shows the sound settings menu. The output section is highlighted.]
4. Change the configuration option to "**High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)**".

   [image: Image shows just the output section of the sound settings menu. The high fidelity option has just been selected.]
5. Observe that the sound quality immediately changes for all sound coming from the computer. No Teams restart required!